# Creating a facebook tab through FB connect

Tags: facebook, api, tabs

I want to do the following:
Get data from my Android app and on the click of a button create a facebook tab on my user's FB page (through FB connect).

**NOTE** - create a tab on **another** user's FB page - not on my own page.

Is this do able, are there any workarounds, are there any other options?

Thanks,

Kilimangaro.

Comment: Please improve the language. There are typos ("to to") and you question is not very clear.

Comment: I've made an attempt to improve your post, I'am however unsure as to what you mean with 'Obama Care' please explain, and provide relative code, with which you've attempted to get data from your app.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Obama care was a joke to light things up :)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#adding

You can either use the JavaScript SDK or the URL Redirect mentioned in the Facebook docs. Both solution will show a panel where the User can select his Pages for adding the App.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Please note- I don't want to add an app to the user account but rather to create a tab over the user FB page.